# Updating variable in a function (python) not working?

Tags: python

I am still new in python and exciting about learning it. This time, I have a function in which I expect to update a variable and use it again **without using for loops**. Please look at my function below:

```
def x_func(y):
    x = 0.
    newx = 0.897*x + (y/3)
    x = newx
    return x
```

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

When I call my function, I get:

```
In [1]:x_func(y)
Out[1]: array([ 0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.        ])
```

However, the expected result is:

```
Out[1]: array([ 0.33333333,  0.96563676,  1.8661761797])
```

I want to **update x** based on newx, and use it again in the function as the new input variable x.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why does this this result indicate to you that `x` is not being assigned a new value? I don't see how you get to your belief about what is/isn't happening from the result given.

Comment: ...if you expect the interpreter to be going back and recalculating formulas based on an updated value... well, that would require a different kind of language. Python doesn't do that; when you perform an assignment, the calculation is run *at that point in time*, and the result *at that point in time* is put in place in the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're actually receiving is correct. Let's work through it here:

```
x = 0.
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
newx = 0.897*x + (y/3)   # newx=([1/3, 2/3, 3/3])
x = newx                 # x = ([1/3, 2/3, 3/3])
```

...since ((0.897*0) + (y/3)) == (y/3), the returned values are as anticipated.

Why would you expect anything different?

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I did not explain well what I want. This is wat I want: 1) The first x = 0 (initial conditions). Using the equation newx = 0.897*x + (y/3), I want this: ``newx = 0.897* 0 + 1/3 = 0.333. 2)´´ The next round I expect this: `newx = 0.897* **0.333** + 2/3 = 0.96563676´, and finally 3) ``newx = 0.897 * **0.96563676** + 3/3 = 1.8661761797´´. I used the name **newx** to avoid doing this: ``for i in range(len(z): x3[i] = 0.897*x3[i-1] + z/3´´. I hope this can clarify my question.

Comment: Python (like C, or Perl, or Ruby, or Java, or any other mainstream procedural language) **simply does not work like that**. If you want automatic recalculation, you need a symbolic language, not a procedural one.

Comment: It is just due to my lack of experience with Python (and programing in general), but I am actually trying to translate a C++ code to python, and it has several functions in which it updates variables. The code is pretty long, but if you want I can copy-and-paste a peace of it for you.

Comment: It's encouraging to hear that you're porting from C++ -- that means that you're not looking for features that don't actually exist. However, I don't think about C++ for less than 1.5x my regular consulting rate, so I'll need to count myself out. :)

Comment: Basically, though, to understand the issue here: Execution flow goes from top to bottom; it doesn't jump back up to recalculate things after you modify a value unless you explicitly write flow control constructs to make it do so.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy. Thank you! I will try to solve the issue in a 'pythonic' way. I am also using a Fortran 77 version of the same program as a reference and it clearly states: **now, updates the variables: X = newX, Y = newY, etc.** I think that was my confusion here, but I appreciate your information about python. Thanks!

Comment: For heavy math work (particularly if performance were important), I'd probably be porting to Julia rather than Python. Even if the intent were eventual use/calling from Python, that's what Pyjulia is for. :)

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is quite simple, actually. Let me explain.

You define a function x_func that takes a numpy vector as input, and outputs a modified vector. Now, you define x = 0. (so, a float of value zero).

Then, the new value for x is

```
0.897 * x  # this is zero
    + y / 3
```

Since the multiplication defaults to zero, we are left to work out `y / 3`. In matrix algebra, the multiplication of a scalar and a vector (numpy array) is done as follows:

`y / 3 = [1,2,3] * (1/3) = [1/3, 2/3, 3/3] = [0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.]`

**This is exactly the result you are seeing!**

The problem in your code is probably the assignment `x = 0.` What would you like to achieve with it? Your explanation is not quite informative enough for me to offer a solution to your problem, even though I can point out to you where it goes wrong.